# Como importo bibliotecas de terceiros para um projeto no Eclipse?

Tags: java, api, library

Estou tentando usar duas bibliotecas de terceiros para um projeto em Java no Eclipse: iText (para gerar um PDF) e JavaMail (para enviar esse PDF por e-mail), mas não estou conseguindo nem importa-las...

Já tentei de tudo. Já arrastei a pasta para o /src do meu projeto, já fui pelo `botão direito > Import...`, já fui pelo `Properties` do projeto... Já fiz de tudo, mas não estou conseguindo adicionar as bibliotecas ao meu CLASSPATH.

Estou com duas dificuldades principais:

1) As pastas das bibliotecas são CHEIAS de arquivos, e eu não entendo nada. Tem mil .jar. Não sei qual é o que eu preciso jogar para dentro do Eclipse.

2) Quando eu jogo TODOS os arquivos (seja pelo `Import...`, seja jogando a pasta inteira, algumas partes das bibliotecas são importadas, mas outras não. Por exemplo: `com.itextpdf.text` sim, tranquilo, mas `com.itextpdf.text.Document` não. Coisa semelhante ocorre com o JavaMail.

Do que eu preciso?

De um tutorial REALMENTE BOM, para alguém QUE ESTÁ COMEÇANDO AGORA... Todos os que eu acho pulam muitas etapas e eu fico perdido. A maioria NEM FALA COMO QUE JOGA A BIBLIOTECA PRA DENTRO DO ECLIPSE. E os outros - que falam -, falam como se fosse a coisa mais simples do mundo.

Estou indo à loucura mesmo.

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: bom, no eclipse para importar um jar você precisa clicar com o botão direito no projeto, ir em `Build Path` > `Configure Build Path`, vai abrir uma janela, nela você vai na aba `Libraries`, agora basta clicar em `Add JARs...` você pode copiar todos para dentro de uma pasta dentro de seu projeto.

Comment: Mas a frente, eu indico a você utilizar algum gerenciador de dependências como o [maven](https://maven.apache.org/) ou o [gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/release-notes.html)